Base locus of nef divisors
Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety (over the complex numbers), and let $D$ be a prime divisor on $X$. Suppose that $D$ is nef, that is for any irreducible curve $C\subset X$ we have $D\cdot C\geq 0$.
Consider the linear system $|D|$, and the rational map associated
$$\phi : X\dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}(\text{H}^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X(D)), \quad x\mapsto [s_0(x):\ldots: s_N(x)],$$
with $s_0,\ldots,s_N$ a basis of the space of global sections of $\mathcal{O}_X(D)$.
Question: Let $y\in X$ be a point such that any curve $C$ passing through $y$ is such that $D\cdot C =0$. Is it true then that $y$ belongs to the base locus of $|D|$?
I would expect the answer is positive, but I am not sure how to prove it. More specifically, I don't see a relation between null intersection product and $s_k(y)=0$, for $k=0,\ldots,N$.

If the divisor $D$ is not effective, then $|D|$ is empty, so its base locus is $X$ and there is nothing to show.
If $D$ is effective, then I claim no such $y$ exists. To see this, write $n$ for the dimension of $X$. Let $A$ be a very ample divisor on $X$ and let $A_1,\ldots,A_{n-1}$ be general elements of the sub-linear system of divisors in $|A|$ which pass through $y$. Then $A_1\cap \cdots \cap A_{n-1}$ is an irreducible curve $C$ through $y$, and $D \cdot C = D \cdot A^{n-1} >0$ because $A$ is very ample.

Thak you for the answer! Your explanation clashes with what I know about nef divisors. You claim no such $y$ exists, thus $\text{Bs}(|D|)$ is empty. Therefore $D$ is base point free, which is not true in general. For instance, take the blow-up of $\mathbb{P}^2$ at two points, and consider the nef divisor $D$ belonging to the facet of the Nef cone associated to the contraction of the strict transform of the line joining the two points. The base locus is not empty.

I don't claim that the base locus of $D$ is empty. I just said that there is no point $y$ such that every curve $C$ through $y$ satisfies $D \cdot C =0$.
